# How To use Query string in java script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have Created calculator project. I have only two pages. Now my question how to pass input field value to another page? trying too many ways its Not Working.

What to do to pass input fields values from one page  to another page?

My input fields code Looks Like

```
<p class="pull-right">DPA Minimum Buyer Contribution<br /></p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right:1%">
            <input type="text" id="txtLocationContactName5" class="txt"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:0%">
```

Another page name `default_results.php` I have created input fields

```
<div class="col-md-5 padding-rht">
    Minimum Buyer Contribution
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 padding-Zero"> 
        <input type="text" id="txtCustomerName3"  class="txt"  />
    </div>
```

I have tired in jQuery script

```
<script>
 $(function () {
        $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {
            var url = "default_results.php?id=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtLocationContactName5").val()) + "&technology=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtCustomerName3").val());
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script
```

but Not working so how to pass value one page to other page ?

Comment: What do you mean by *Not working*?

Comment: value not pass one page to other page.

Comment: Are the values in the url when you are redirected to the 2nd page?

Comment: how are you trying to retrieve the params on the second page?

Comment: As per your question "#txtCustomerName3 " is on another page!

Comment: @psylogic #txtCustomerName another page  i want pass value from  txtLocationContactName5  to #txtCustomerName3

Comment: so when #txtCustomerName3  doesn't exist in the page from where you are redirecting how can you send its value ??  "&technology=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtCustomerName3").val()), how is this possible???

Comment: @psylogic sorry i am not clear i am New in  javascript  please explain  little  bit more about it please

Comment: ASSUMPTION: you want to pass the value of `txtLocationContactName5` in page A to  `txtCustomerName3` in page B . Am i right ?@sumathiN

Answer (score 1):

You're making life hard for yourself! A simple form is needed to help you pass data to another page :). See here for info on html Forms - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Here is a simple example for you:

```
<form action="page_2_link" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="field1" value="easy">
   <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then on the second page you can do this to retrieve the form data:

```
<?php
   $blah = $_POST['field1']; // this now has the posted fields value
?>
```

I have given the second page answer in PHP as you have used this as a tag for this question, so I hope you are using this or my answer won't work.

Comment: Without submit buttton  its possible

Comment: How about using cookies or localstorage then?

Comment: @sumathiN You can't have a submit button or a form?
If its the former, you can submit using a regular link/button also.

`document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`